# Default value for kwargs with ipywidgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, keyword-argument

I am creating a function which uses `ipywidgets` to create sliders for varying inputs, and I would like to set the default value for these sliders.

At the same time, I would like my function to accept an undefined set of values with `**kwargs`, where the keywords indicate which items in a dictionary my sliders should act on. As a simple test case:

```
from ipywidgets import *
@interact(year = (2011,2021,1), 
          cat = (0,100,1), 
          man = (0,100,1)) # only make sliders for year, cat, man

def test(year = 2011, **kwargs): #default year, now I only need default everything else
    data_set = {'cat':("Cat in the hat", 1000), 
                'dog':("Dog and bone", 1750), 
                'man':("Man about the house",114)} #info on cat, dog and man
    for dictKey, growth in kwargs.iteritems():
        itemName, itemValue = data_set[dictKey] #use kw argument to look in data set
        newValue = itemValue * (1 + growth * (year - 2011)/100)
        print("Item was: {}\nInitial value: {} \nGrowth: {}%\nNew Value: {}\n".format(itemName, itemValue, growth, newValue))
```

The output in Jupyter notebooks looks like this:

[image: Jupyter Notebooks result]

As you can see, the interact sliders code specifies which values to lookup and return in my function.

However I would also like to set the default value of all the `**kwargs` to zero. All the answers I've found rely on some knowledge of the `data_set` or the arguments that will be passed. I only know that the argument names will refer to keys in my dictionary, and will have a value 1-100, but I don't know how to set the default like I have for `year`?

---

*NB. Sorry if this is very basic or has been asked before, I am still new to Python so don't know what to search for yet. Also if you spot any obvious improvements to my code, please enlighten me in the comments!*

Answer (score 0):

The class `ZeroDict` extends a dictionary and returns 0 whenever an inexistent key is requested:

```
class ZeroDict:
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        self.dictionary = dictionary

    def __getitem__(self, ref):
        try:
            return self.dictionary[ref]
        except KeyError:
            return 0

def f(**kwargs):
    kwargs = ZeroDict(kwargs)
    print (kwargs['a']+kwargs['b']*kwargs['c']) # print(a+b*c)


f()
f(a=4)
```